# Japanese term for “cookie cutter”

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, idioms

I’m looking for a term in Japanese that conveys the same sense of repeated design with minimal or limited variation that is implied by the English phrase “cookie cutter”.  My particular interest is in trying to describe software project templates, but this could also refer to the design of houses, paintings or other work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

量産型 (“mass-produced”) can be used in a similar fashion. It has the literal meaning when used with something actually mass-produced in a factory, but can be used idiomatically on things that are not mass-produced to insinuate they are cookie-cutter, all the same, boring, lack creativity, etc.